# Getting Error Error: EIO: i/o error at React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am developing an application using node.js for the backend and react.js for the frontend.
both of the folders at the same directory.

```
root
|_____backend
|_____frontend
```

I finished coding yesterday and when I tried to run the react application today without any changes it gave me this error

```
node:internal/fs/utils:345
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EIO: i/o error, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:727:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:471:19)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1116:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<path>/frontend/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/lib/index.js:12:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14) {
  errno: -5,
  syscall: 'read',
  code: 'EIO'
}
```

I tried to reinstall the node packages but no gain.
what seems to be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: give more info: 1) sources where error occurs, 2) version of node, 3) os, etc

Comment: 1) I just run 'npm start' and that give me the error no other err messages
2) Node version is  v17.7.1
3) OS fedora 34

Comment: This might indicate a physical fault with your disk. You may try to run some hardware diagnostic.

Comment: @tromgy I think you are right. I have cloned my project into another disk partition and it runs okay. I think I have some disk corruptions. thank you!

Comment: I ran into this issue using VSCode and WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Fix was to restart WSL2 using wsl --shutdown or just restarting your machine. I believe the problem was that the virtual hard disk had run out of memory.

Comment: @GabrielWamunyu You are a lifesaver!